# Doxygen custom element and list

Tags: documentation, doxygen, documentation-generation

**What I want to achieve:**

I want to list certain things (think `todo`, in my examples they are arbitrarily `Summons`) in the documentation I am generating with Doxygen. I want to use a custom item (`\summon`) so I can ahve a list of all `Summons` documented in a file, and also to generate a page listing all of them in the entire system, split up by file.

(I am only really concerned with generating HTML documentation here, not latex.)

Here's an example:

In documentation for Foo.c (say `foo_c.html`, or whatever):

Summons:

- Summon an Angora goat
- Summon a Boer goat

In documentation for Bar.c:

Summons:

- Summon an elephant of murderous disposition

In some other documentation page for all documented Summons (say `summons_global_list.c`, accessible from a navigation tab or similar):

Foo.c:

- Summon an Angora goat
- Summon a Boer goat

Bar.c:

- Summon an elephant of murderous disposition

---

**What I can and can't do so far:**

Using an /xrefitem alias (`ALIASES += "summon=\xrefitem req \"Summon\" \"Summons\" "`), I can get `todo` style lists. That's fine.

However...

```
/*!
 * ...other things go here..
 *
 * \summon an Angora goat
 */

 ...code here...

/*
 * \summon a Boer goat
 */
```

gives me the list header twice, e.g.:

Summons:

- Summon an Angora goat

Summons:

- Summon a Boer goat

*How can I get around that?*

*I am also rather stumped about how I might get a custom page listing all the "Summons" by file.*

Comment: what's up with the summoning? :D

Comment: This question got bumped up, but I don't see a change. I did some tests but it looks to me that the mentioned issue doesn't exist anymore in the current version of doxygen (1.8.14).

Comment: @albert this question is six years old. I expect a lot has changed in that time.